# Django self join with ForeignKey (ORM)

Tags: python, django

I have an `Event` Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    cancels_event = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm analysing lots of event messages, but firstly I need to check if the event has been canceled.

Let's say I receive an `Event_1`, then I receive an `Event_2` with `Event_2.cancels_event=Event_1`, so `Event_2` cancels `Event_1`.

I want to find out, given a subset of Events, which Events from this subset have been canceled.

In SQL I'd use a join with self:

```
SELECT * FROM Event e1
JOIN Event e2
ON e1.id = e2.cancels_event
```

But I don't know how to do it within Django ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Event.objects.filter(
    event__isnull=False
)
```

or if you want to prevent returning the same `Event` multiple times, you can add `.distinct()`:

```
Event.objects.filter(
    event__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

This works because the default [**`related_query_name=…`** value <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for your `cancels_event` is `event`. You can rename this to `canceling_events` for example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # …
    cancels_event = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='canceling_events'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Then the query is:

```
Event.objects.filter(
    canceling_events__isnull=False
)
```

Comment: how would that help me to find out, if an event is canceled?

Comment: @Rafaó: the standard `related_query_name` of your `cancels_event` is `Event`. So here you make a `JOIN` on the same table, and thus obtain all `Event`s for which there is at least one `Event` that refers with `cancels_event` to that `Event`.

Comment: @Rafaó: you can use `print(Event.objects.filter(event__isnull=False))` to print the query that Django will make.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't use join but works.

```
canceled_list= Event.objects.all().values_list('cancels_event')

result = Event.objects.filter(pk__in = canceled_list)
```